# Bundle not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, bundle

I am trying to send data from activity to fragment,but in fragment i am getting null instead of my values,following is my code can any one help me with this?

```
String nofrndthere="nofrnds";
            String frndthere="frnds";
            if(jsonary.length()==0)
            {
               // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Null",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("nofrndsavailable", nofrndthere);
                HomeFragment fragobj = new HomeFragment();
                fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
            }
            else if(jsonary.length()!=0)
            {
              //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Not Null",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("frndsavailable", frndthere);
                HomeFragment fragobj = new HomeFragment();
                fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
            }
```

HomeFragment

```
    public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

    private FragmentTabHost tabHost;
    private SearchView searchView;
    private String strtext;
    private String strtextss,strtextfnrdval;


    public HomeFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        tabHost = new FragmentTabHost(getActivity());
        tabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.layout.my_parent_fragment);


        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        strtext = bundle.getString("user_login_id");
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            strtextss = bundle.getString("nofrndsavailable");
            strtextfnrdval= bundle.getString("frndsavailable");

        }
        System.out.println("DATASSSSS :  " +strtextss+strtextfnrdval);

        System.out.println("<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Session ID :  " + strtext+strtextss+strtextfnrdval);



        Bundle arg1 = new Bundle();
        arg1.putInt("Arg for Frag1", 1);
        if(strtext!=null) {
            arg1.putString("user_logid", strtext);
        }

        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("one").setIndicator(getTabIndicator(tabHost.getContext(), R.drawable.icon_profile_tabs,"Home")), DiscoverFragment.class, arg1);
        Bundle arg2 = new Bundle();

        arg2.putInt("Arg for Frag2", 2);

        if(strtext!=null) {
            arg2.putString("user_logid_sectab", strtext);
        }

        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Sec").
                setIndicator(getTabIndicator(tabHost.getContext(), R.drawable.icon_frnds_tab,"Invite")), ShopFragment.class, arg2);


        Bundle arg3 = new Bundle();
        arg3.putInt("Arg for Frag3", 3);

        if(strtext!=null) {
            arg3.putString("user_logid_thirdtab", strtext);
        }



        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Third").
                setIndicator(getTabIndicator(tabHost.getContext(), R.drawable.icon_wish_tab,"Wish")), Thirdtab.class, arg3);


        Bundle arg4 = new Bundle();
        arg4.putInt("Arg for Frag4", 4);
        if(strtext!=null) {
            arg4.putString("user_logid_fourthtab", strtext);
        }


        if(strtextss == getArguments().getString("nofrndsavailable"))
        {
           // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Null in home", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            System.out.println("Null in home");
            tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Four").
                    setIndicator(getTabIndicator(tabHost.getContext(), R.drawable.icon_notification_tab, "Alert")), FourthTabs.class, arg4);

        }
        else if(strtextfnrdval == getArguments().getString("frndsavailable"))
        {
          //  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Not Null in home", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            System.out.println("NotNull in home");
            tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Four").
                    setIndicator(getTabIndicator(tabHost.getContext(), R.drawable.icon_fnrdalert, "Alert")), FourthTabs.class, arg4);

        }

        return tabHost;


    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }

    public View getTabIndicator(Context context, int icon,String text) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, null);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.indicatorImageView);
        iv.setImageResource(icon);
        TextView txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txttb);
        txt.setText(text);
        return view;
    }



}
```

Comment: can you tell i which method of `Fragment` you are trying to get `getArguments().getString("");`

Comment: Which values are null? Does getArguments() already return null?

Comment: @BenjaminScharbau see my edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before you open the fragment this is how you can attach the bundle to it. following code should be in your activity to put the bundle in the fragment.

```
Fragment fragment = new YourFragmentClass();
Bundle args = new Bundle();

args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
fragment.setArguments(args);
```

now that you have attached the bundle open the fragment .

Things which you have to do is Override `onCreate()` method in your fragment and this is how you will receive the bundle.

```
private String mParam1; // these are global variable to get the data
private String mParam2; // after you receive the data, it can be used under `onActivityCreated()`

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1,null);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2,null);
// I have updated the code thisis how you can check which string is empty.
// cause if you try to do some work on null object you will get error
        if(mParam1 == null){
           // it is empty
        }else{
           // it is not empty
        }
        if(mParam2 == null){
           // it is empty
        }else{
           // it is not empty
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

  // here you can use mParam1 and mParam2
}
```

> Update
>   with conversation I had with you, you can start your fragment though your activity like this to tell the fragment if the array is null or not

```
HomeFragment fragobj = new HomeFragment();

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
if(jsonary.length()==0){
bundle.putBoolean("isAvailable", false);
}else{
bundle.putBoolean("isAvailable", true);
}

fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
```

and in the onCreate() method of your fragment this is how you can read the boolean value

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
         boolean mParam1 = getArguments().getBoolean("isAvailable",false);
    }
}
```

> Updated

ok now i realize what you are doing (fragment is already started before setting the bundle), you can try this. (it is quite cheeky )

make a method inside your `HomeFragment`

```
public static void setData(boolean isAvailable){
 // here you will get the actual data
}
```

Now in your Activity when you get the `JSONArray` depending on that you can that you can do this.

```
HomeFragment.setData(true/false)
```

Comment: @Lakhan, mate, you are assigning, two different bundles to two different fragment objects in your activity, that is why when you start the fragment only one of the String would be available. because at a given time whichever fragment you start it has only one String in it

Comment: where is that two diff assigining?

Comment: @Lakhan, in your activity, if else condition, only one of the String would have the text other would be empty

Comment: @Lakhan, i have updated the answer. you either add both the String to the bundle or if you don't want to do that, check in the fragment which string is available to use.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100645/discussion-between-lakhan-and-pankaj-nimgade).

Comment: i add that condition still its same

Comment: @Lakhan yes it will be same. Because you are not adding the both the string in the activity to the bundle, because of your if-else condition only one instance of bundle gets attached to the instance of Fragment with only one string attached to it

Comment: @Lakhan I have updated the answer again this will work in your condition

Answer (score 0):

From your question I think you are getting `user_login_id` as null from bundle

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
strtext = bundle.getString("user_login_id");
```

This is because you have not put any string with `user_login_id` in your bundle

```
 if(jsonary.length()==0)
  {
         // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Null",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
         bundle.putString("nofrndsavailable", nofrndthere);
         bundle.putString("user_login_id", <userid>); //put user id here

         HomeFragment fragobj = new HomeFragment();
         fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
   }
   else if(jsonary.length()!=0)
   {
          //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Not Null",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
          bundle.putString("frndsavailable", frndthere);
          bundle.putString("user_login_id",<userid>);// put user id here
          HomeFragment fragobj = new HomeFragment();
          fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
     }
```